# Test dial activity with espresso

Tags: java, android, testing, android-espresso, android-testing

I am trying to test a click on a button that sends the user to the Phone activity... Like this:

```
public void callNumber(String number){
        Uri numberUri = Uri.parse("tel:"+number);
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, numberUri);
        startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

Well... but when I run this test:

```
    @Rule
public IntentsTestRule<HelpView> mActivityRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(HelpView.class, true, true);

@ClassRule
static public DeviceAnimationTestRule deviceAnimationTestRule = new DeviceAnimationTestRule();


    @Test
    public void clickDialButtonTest(){
        onView(withId(R.id.help_viewpager)).perform(swipeLeft());
        onView(withId(R.id.help_viewpager)).perform(swipeLeft());

        onView(withId(R.id.phone_call_btn)).perform(click());
        intended(allOf(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)));
    }
```

I get this:

**Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.**

**Edit:**

Actually, what happens is that Espresso doesn't wait for the switch in the ViewPager to complete. So when the button is clicked, nothing is happening. I can fix the problem with this:

```
@Test
public void clickOnMapButtonTest() {
    onView(withId(R.id.help_viewpager)).perform(swipeLeft());
    onView(withId(R.id.help_viewpager)).perform(swipeLeft());

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Assert.fail();
    }

    onView(withId(R.id.phone_call_btn)).perform(click());

    intended(allOf(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL), toPackage("com.android.dialer")));
}
```

But this looks a bit wrong... Maybe there's a better way. Does any one has a better option?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using `ActivityTestRule` instead of `IntentsTestRule`.

Edit:

You shouldn't use `Thread.sleep(2000)`... The Espresso way of "waiting" is using `IdlingResource`. [Here's a simple explanation of you can follow.](http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/04/espresso-custom-idling-resource.html)

Comment: No... I am using IntentsTestRule

Comment: Ok and are you disabling animations for your tests? You can do that e.g. with a `ClassRule` like [that](https://github.com/VictorAlbertos/DeviceAnimationTestRule).

Comment: I removed the animations... But the problems are still there. I am not testing any methods that contain animations anyway

Comment: But did you disable activity transitions? You don't have animations but you have a default transition of the dialer activity. I created a test project with a `Button` that executes your exact code (that starts a dialer), and the test succeeded without any issues. Try commenting out `ViewPager` lines for a test and see if that makes the test succeed.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `IntentsTestRule`, `Intents.init()` will start recording intents after activity is created, and `Intents.release()` will clear out all recorded intents after the activity is finished. Using `IntentsTestRule` is problematic here because `Intents.release()` clears out all recorded intents when `HelpView` activity finishes and navigates to the `Dialer` activity before you get a chance to verify the intent with `intended`.

Instead, you can use `ActivityTestRule` and call `Intents.init()` before launching activity, and call `Intents.release()` after the test like this:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule <HelpView> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule(HelpView.class, true, true);

@ClassRule
static public DeviceAnimationTestRule deviceAnimationTestRule = new DeviceAnimationTestRule();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
       // start recording intents before activity launch
       Intents.init();
    }

    @After
    public void cleanUp() {
       // clears out all recorded intents after test completes
       Intents.release();
    }

    @Test
    public void clickDialButtonTest(){
        onView(withId(R.id.help_viewpager)).perform(swipeLeft());
        onView(withId(R.id.help_viewpager)).perform(swipeLeft());

        onView(withId(R.id.phone_call_btn)).perform(click());
        // now, we can verify Intent.Action Dial against the
        // list of recorded intents
        intended(allOf(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)));
    }
```